# Segmentation fault 11, despite plenty of memory being allocated

Tags: c, string, memory, structure

I'm running into a strange error. When I compile my code, it gives me the following message:

```
%i??
[R?
R?
?
Desktop/prog2
Terminal
51/sls2t0f16cd4dzl3640n4p2w0000gn/T/
private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.AJrzeyltFv/Render
ION=343.6
ER=Frank
Listeners
in:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin
ank
E=/Users/Frank
nk/Desktop/prog2

Segmentation fault: 11
logout
```

I understand that this is due to a memory issue. However, I gave dictionary2 the same memory as the original dictionary, so why would it not be able to compile the entire list?

Here's my code (I know it's a little on the long side, but I feel that it is all necessary to convey what is going on):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct entry
{
    char word[15];
    char definition[50];
};


void dictionarySort(struct entry dictionary[]) {
    int i, j, k, word1, word2, dict2Length = 1;
    bool bnf = false;
    struct entry dictionary2[100] = {{}};

    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(&dictionary->word[0]); i++) {
        strcpy(&dictionary2[0].word[i], &dictionary[0].word[i]);
    }


    i = 0;
    word1 = 1;
    word2 = 0;



    while (isalpha(dictionary[word1].word[0])) {

        while (i <= strlen(&dictionary->word[word1])) {
            //printf("%c", dictionary[word1].word[i]);
            if (dictionary[word1].word[i] == dictionary2[word2].word[i]) {
                i++;
                bnf = false;
            }
            else if (dictionary[word1].word[i] < dictionary[word2].word[i]) {
                //insert section to prevent back-and-forth cycling
                if (bnf == false) {
                    word2--;
                    bnf = true;
                }
                else { //(dictionary[word1].word[i] < dictionary[word2].word[i])
                    //open up new index by moving everything above up one, insert at word
                    for (j = dict2Length; j > word2; j--) {
                        //word
                        for (k = 0; k <= strlen(&dictionary2->word[0]); k++) {
                            strcpy(&dictionary2[j+1].word[k], &dictionary2[j].word[k]);
                        }
                        //definition
                        for (k = 0; k <= strlen(&dictionary2->word[0]); k++) {
                            strcpy(&dictionary2[j+1].definition[k], &dictionary2[j].definition[k]);
                        }
                    }

                    //for (k = 0; k < strlen(&dictionary1->word[word1]))
                    for (k = 0; k < strlen(dictionary[word1].word); k++) {
                        strcpy(&dictionary2[word2].word[k], &dictionary[word1].word[k]);
                    }
                    for (k = 0; k < strlen(dictionary[word1].definition); k++) {
                        strcpy(&dictionary2[word2].definition[k], &dictionary[word1].definition[k]);
                    }
                    dict2Length++;
                    break;
                }   
            }
            else {
                //insert section to prevent back-and-forth cycling
                if (bnf == false) {
                    word2++;
                    bnf = true;
                }
                else { //(dictionary[word1].word[i] < dictionary[word2].word[i])
                    //open up new index by moving everything above up one, insert at word
                    for (j = dict2Length; j > word2; j--) {
                        //word
                        for (k = 0; k <= strlen(&dictionary2->word[0]); k++) {
                            strcpy(&dictionary2[j+1].word[k], &dictionary2[j].word[k]);
                        }
                        //definition
                        for (k = 0; k <= strlen(&dictionary2->word[0]); k++) {
                            strcpy(&dictionary2[j+1].definition[k], &dictionary2[j].definition[k]);
                        }
                    }

                    for (k = 0; k < strlen(dictionary[word1].word); k++) {
                        strcpy(&dictionary2[word2].word[k], &dictionary[word1].word[k]);
                    }
                    for (k = 0; k < strlen(dictionary[word1].definition); k++) {
                        strcpy(&dictionary2[word2].definition[k], &dictionary[word1].definition[k]);
                    }
                    dict2Length++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        word1++;
    }


    word2 = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < dict2Length; i++) {
        printf ("%s\n", dictionary2[i].word);
    }

}

int main (void) {
    struct entry dictionary[100] = 
    {{"aerie", "a high nest"},
    {"abyss", "a bottomless pit"},
    {"ahoy", "a nautical call of greeting"},
    {"addle", "to become confused"},
    {"aardvark", "a burrowing African mammal"},
    {"agar", "a jelly made of seaweed"},
    {"acumen", "mentally sharp; keen"},
    {"aigrette", "an ornamental cluster of feathers"},
    {"affix", "to attach"},
    {"ajar", "partially opened"}};
    dictionarySort(dictionary);
}
```

Comment: A segmentation fault is a memory issue, but it's not a problem with *running out* of memory.  It's a problem with your program attempting to access memory that is not assigned to it.  Usually this arises from a bad array index, uninitialized or dangling pointer, or similar.

Comment: Do you have access to a debugger of some sort?  Where the program freezes should show you exactly where the fault in question lies.

Comment: You can use the `qsort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're having trouble calculating your dictionary length. When you run it, it says the length is something like 1701996321, which seems much higher than it should be. Then, on the last for loop, right towards the end where you print the words, you probably go out of bounds for the dictionary. Comment out that printf and you'll see the error is gone. I'd start by looking into dict2Lenght.

```
for (i = 0; i < dict2Length; i++) {
    printf ("%s\n", dictionary2[i].word);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line has the indexing back to front

```
strcpy(&dictionary2[0].word[i], &dictionary[0].word[i]);
```

it should be

```
strcpy(&dictionary2[i].word[0], &dictionary[i].word[0]);
```

or even better

```
strcpy(dictionary2[i].word, dictionary[i].word);
```

Also, your loop `for (i...)` is based on `strlen(&dictionary->word[0])`. Should you be passing the number of array entries as an argument to `dictionarySort()`? As it stands, the loop is based on the length of the first dictionary entry.

I have to pass on debugging the sorting. It is horrible. Just use `qsort()`.

Answer (score 2):

use `qsort`

```
void dictionarySort(struct entry dictionary[]) {
    struct entry dictionary2[100] = {{"",""}};
    int i, n;

    for (i = 0; i < 100 && dictionary[i].word[0] != '\0'; ++i){
        dictionary2[i] = dictionary[i];
    }
    n = i;

    qsort(dictionary2, n, sizeof(*dictionary2), strcmp);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf ("%s\n", dictionary2[i].word);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is returning an error on strcmp. Isn't it a function that requires arguments?

Comment: @FrankTocci I think perhaps it's warning. try cast  as `(int (*)(const void*,const void*))strcmp` or write wrapper function.

Comment: wrapper funciotn like as `int dic_cmp(const void *a, const void *b){ return strcmp((char*)a, (char*)b); }`, ...  `dic_cmp` instead of `strcmp`.